# How to load SQL expression as mapped attribute having relationship with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

Let's have two SQLAlchemy models:

```py
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("parent.id"), nullable=False)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", lazy="joined")
```

What I try to achieve is having a boolean attribute (let's call it `has_deps`) on `Parent` which will be `True` when there are children for a given parent.

I have also some constraints:

- It must be accessible when I convert the object to a dict
- It must not generate a correlated subquery

I tried different methods :

- Using `column_property` with `exists` gave me a correlated subquery

```py
Parent.has_deps = column_property(
    exists([Child.parent_id]).where(Child.parent_id == Parent.id)
)
```

results in :

```
SELECT parent.id AS parent_id, EXISTS (SELECT child.parent_id FROM child WHERE child.parent_id = parent.id) AS anon_1, parent.id AS id_1, child_1.id AS child_1_id, child_1.parent_id AS child_1_parent_id 
FROM parent LEFT OUTER JOIN child AS child_1 ON parent.id = child_1.parent_id
```

- Using an `hybrid_property` is not loaded at query time nor accessible with dict and has no purpose for that

```py
@has_deps.expression
def has_deps(cls):
    return case([(Child.parent_id != None, True)], else_=False)
```

(will not even be linked to the left outer alias join generated by the relationship)

As an example, this is the query I want the ORM to produce by just doing `session.query(Parent).all()`:

```
SELECT parent.id AS parent_id, CASE WHEN child_1.parent_id IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END AS has_deps, parent.id AS id_1, child_1.id AS child_1_id, child_1.parent_id AS child_1_parent_id 
FROM parent LEFT OUTER JOIN child AS child_1 ON parent.id = child_1.parent_id
```